# Can't remove home-brew package

Tags: homebrew

I am encountering an issue with Homebrew where I have a package that is seemingly uninstalled, but it's still accessible.

- Running `brew list` shows that the package is no longer present.
- However, if I try to get the version of the package `pyinstaller --version` I see that it is indeed still accessible
- If I check the location of the package `which pyinstaller`, I see that it is located in `/opt/homebrew/bin/pyinstaller`
- If I try again to uninstall the package `brew uninstall pyinstaller`, I get an error that the package is already uninstalled `Error: No such keg: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/pyinstaller`

I am tempted to try to force remove the package by doing something like `rm -fr /opt/homebrew/bin/pyinstaller` but I don't want to mess anything up.

[image]

Comment: Just some information on my computer. I am using a Mac M1.

Comment: What is the output of `brew doctor`?